# Google Sheets function to sum values where other column's date is today?

Tags: date, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a google sheet with the following columns:

```
Column A: Timestamp
Column B: Description
Column C: Calories
```

I want to create a sum of "Today's Calories" on another sheet. Here is the formula I have developed so far:

```
=SUMIFS('Form Responses 1'!C:C, 'Form Responses 1'!A:A, TODAY())
```

The code above gives the value "0" even though there are entries for today.

So I want to sum the values from "Calories" but only those rows whose "Timestamp" value is from today. The Timestamp values look like this:

```
6/15/2020 11:02:15
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this works

```
=SUMPRODUCT(INT('Form Responses 1'!A2:A)=today(), 'Form Responses 1'!C2:C)
```

[More on sumproduct](http://More%20on%20sumproduct:%20https://blog.sheetgo.com/google-sheets-formulas/sumproduct-formula-google-sheets/#:~:text=The%20SUMPRODUCT%20formula%20in%20Google%20Sheets%20multiplies%20corresponding%20items%20within,arrays%20and%20add%20them%20up.)

Comment: INT() returns the date-part of the timestamp. The use of sumproduct is a rather personal preference I guess. When used with a condition it behaves like sumif.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
=ArrayFormula(SUMIFS(C2:C, LEFT(A2:A,9)*1, TODAY()))
```

[image]

The `TODAY` function uses time as being `0:00:00`. So today is `6/15/2020 0:00:00`.
That is why the timestamp will never match unless it is at exactly midnight.

So we use the `LEN` function to take just the date from out timestamp.

Functions used:

- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`SUMIFS`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3238496)
- [`LEFT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094079)

Answer (score 0):

The closest to the solution you already have would be to just use >= instead of =

Due to the nature of time, you will probably not have entries from the future :)  So this should work:

```
=SUMIFS('Form Responses 1'!C:C, 'Form Responses 1'!A:A,">="&TODAY())
```